# How to send push notification in IONIC app on the basis of some condition?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have to schedule a push notification in the app which should be shown after every 3 weeks and should remind the customer about the last order they have done. My app is in `IONIC - Angular`.

IONIC - 5

Comment: what about the backend? I think this should be done in the BE not FE application

Comment: The backend is in PHP

Comment: you can use Location Notifications for this and schedule them.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications

Comment: Will it work even after app is killed ?